# Source for wm_concat

Tags: database, oracle

I've been assigned to a new project, that uses Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production. Inside the project most 'sql' statements make heavy use of the unsupported function wm_concat. It seems like the wm_concat is only available in the commercial version.

Does anyone have the source to wm_concat so that I can use it with the Express version?

Comment: Btw, just a note to Jim Garrison, luser droog, alecxe, Klas Mellbourn, Stony who closed the question. This was intended as a reference and possible better version of wm_concat.

Answer (score 4):

Following is what I'm using in its place. Hope it is useful to somebody on the net.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE wm_concat_impl
   AUTHID CURRENT_USER
AS OBJECT (
   curr_str   VARCHAR2 (32767),
   STATIC FUNCTION odciaggregateinitialize (sctx IN OUT wm_concat_impl)
      RETURN NUMBER,
   MEMBER FUNCTION odciaggregateiterate (
      SELF   IN OUT   wm_concat_impl,
      p1     IN       VARCHAR2
   )
      RETURN NUMBER,
   MEMBER FUNCTION odciaggregateterminate (
      SELF          IN       wm_concat_impl,
      returnvalue   OUT      VARCHAR2,
      flags         IN       NUMBER
   )
      RETURN NUMBER,
   MEMBER FUNCTION odciaggregatemerge (
      SELF    IN OUT   wm_concat_impl,
      sctx2   IN       wm_concat_impl
   )
      RETURN NUMBER
);
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY wm_concat_impl
IS
   STATIC FUNCTION odciaggregateinitialize (sctx IN OUT wm_concat_impl)
      RETURN NUMBER
   IS
   BEGIN
      sctx := wm_concat_impl (NULL);
      RETURN odciconst.success;
   END;
   MEMBER FUNCTION odciaggregateiterate (
      SELF   IN OUT   wm_concat_impl,
      p1     IN       VARCHAR2
   )
      RETURN NUMBER
   IS
   BEGIN
      IF (curr_str IS NOT NULL)
      THEN
         curr_str := curr_str || ',' || p1;
      ELSE
         curr_str := p1;
      END IF;

      RETURN odciconst.success;
   END;
   MEMBER FUNCTION odciaggregateterminate (
      SELF          IN       wm_concat_impl,
      returnvalue   OUT      VARCHAR2,
      flags         IN       NUMBER
   )
      RETURN NUMBER
   IS
   BEGIN
      returnvalue := curr_str;
      RETURN odciconst.success;
   END;
   MEMBER FUNCTION odciaggregatemerge (
      SELF    IN OUT   wm_concat_impl,
      sctx2   IN       wm_concat_impl
   )
      RETURN NUMBER
   IS
   BEGIN
      IF (sctx2.curr_str IS NOT NULL)
      THEN
         SELF.curr_str := SELF.curr_str || ',' || sctx2.curr_str;
      END IF;

      RETURN odciconst.success;
   END;
END;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION wm_concat (p1 VARCHAR2)
   RETURN VARCHAR2
   AGGREGATE USING wm_concat_impl;
/
```

Comment: +1 It's always nice to see someone adding information like this to help others.  (Although I think it's worth mentioning that `LISTAGG` is probably a better solution, if a code change is possible.)  Even though `WM_CONCAT` it's an "undocumented" function, I wonder if there is an official Oracle 11g solution.  Based on [this thread](https://forums.oracle.com/message/2427656), and the referenced patch, on 10g you could separately download Workspace Manager, which I assume comes with that function.

Comment: Thanks jonearles, I will look into Workspace Manager. Though yes there is LISTAGG, and stragg that are better solution than using a un-documented function.